# Not function in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use the NOT function to run Sql from table  Projects .But it is giving Syntax error and the desired result is to get all data from table projects except where value in coloumn_2 is image

```
Coloumn_1 Coloumn_2 Coloumn_3  Type 
2335      Image     Value 1    Single
2335      Name 2    Value 2    NULL 
2346      Name 3    Value 3    MULTI
2234      Name 4    Value 4    Single
2235      Name 5    Value 5    Single
```

This is the current function using

```
public function get_all_projects()
{
    $params = array( ':affiliate_id' => $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_id']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Projects AND NOT (coloumn_2 = 'image')";
    $stmt = parent::query($sql, $params);
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
        $projects[] = $row;
    endwhile;
    return $projects;
}
```

Comment: `AND NOT`, maybe just `!=`

Answer (score 1):

> desired result is to get all data from table projects except where value in coloumn_2 is image

This query may give you your desired result.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE coloumn_2 != 'image'";
```

Answer (score 0):

`NOT` should be put into `WHERE` clause.

If `NULL` in `coloumn_2` is not desired, use:

```
SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE NOT (coloumn_2 = 'image')
```

If `NULL` in `coloumn_2` is also desired, use:

```
SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE NOT (coloumn_2 <=> 'image')
```

Comment: As is always the case, care should be taken determining whether or not one desires null values, such as in the column Type.

Comment: see, now I learned something from you :p   ... I would have typed something like `SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE col2 != 'image' or col2 is null;`